# How many of you have upgraded Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, 13.04

I have been using Ubuntu 12.10 since opening, since April I was waiting the pop-up that tell us that there is a new version available, now I have seen this message and I have a question.

How many of you have upgraded Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04? Can you tell me what is your experience in this time? Positive and negative comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Not constructive!!! What could be better that have an opinion from other, what could be better that a life experience...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer only reflects the situation on my box, an Acer Aspire 5750G notebook.

Positive:

1. Ubuntu One icon in the status menu.
2. System settings - Details - Graphics displays the right name of my driver
3. Unity Tweak Manager in Ubuntu Software Repository.
4. More lenses and scopes available.
5. Lenses work faster.

Negative

1. Brightness Fn-left Fn-right doesn't work, even not with acpi_backligt=vendor etc (switched to the old 12.10 kernel to make it work)
2. Desktop solid color (except black) does not work.
3. A lot of GPU hungs. Screen freezes (e.g. during screen scrolling). Hard reboot needed.
4. The first minute after boot, the 'load' is very high and lenses don't work.
5. Nautilus is naked like never before.

Because of all these GPU hungs I now use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS if I have to do work. 13.04 is back to one of my sandbox partitions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, because I have lots of things to do these days and I won't have time to solve any problem, I prefer to wait and upgrade later, actually this version (12.10) is working fine for me.

Comment: read the second post in the link i posted at the end @ your brightness issue

Answer (score 1):

I had no issue but I upgraded during beta testing, be sure to read
[Raring (13.04) known bugs and work arounds](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2141858)
Currently using 2 clean installs of raring (did one a couple days before the release candidate came out)

Answer (score 1):

I never upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 as I was happy with 12.04. But when I upgraded to 13.04 everything worked fine except for one very little problem and that too it was not Ubuntu 13.04 itself. I faced problem with my Nvidia Drivers. I installed current version and still had a fair amount of lag while opening up the dash or dragging windows across the screen. It was becoming very frustrating especially when I had to do some urgent work.

I know this is driver issue as I did face the exact problem in 12.04, but no sooner I switched to post-release updates (version current-update) driver all problems were gone. I couldn't find the same option in 13.04 so after using it for a week I had to downgrade back to 12.04. I think I will stick with 12.04 for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I really think it depends upon each individual user. I'd say Ubuntu 13.04 is the same as 12.10 , only way faster. I, for one, haven't had any problems with it. This link should give you the qualitative analysis (performance-wise) for both the releases:

http://www.hecticgeek.com/2013/04/performance-ubuntu-13-04-review/